# asp.net mvc taking offline for testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, offline

I need to test a feature in a live "asp.net mvc" web site and would want to block access to the site while testing,  how would you recommend doing that? Is it possible to block access and still be able to test as an anonymous user? (I need to test the process as a user that's not logged in).

Comment: Can you set up a beta/test server?

Comment: I can't set up a test server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create **HttpModule** that will check is **IsTesting** property is set.
If **IsTesting** is true, than redirect all requests to under_construction.html, except requests from specific IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give it a try.